# Jumble up names in the table column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, obfuscation

My requirement is to jumble up the names in the oracle table for obfuscation purpose as shown below

Rules

1. same record should not get the same name
2. Jumbling should be done based on the gender
3. Logic should be totally random

Table **employee**

| ID | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | M |
| 2 | Pascal | M |
| 3 | Robin | M |
| 4 | Stephanie | F |
| 5 | Arya | F |

Table **employee** -expcted

| ID | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Robin | M |
| 2 | Peter | M |
| 3 | Pascal | M |
| 4 | Arya | F |
| 5 | Stephanie | F |

What I tried till now is mentioned in the below link, but somehow I am not able to fix it, as the data can be huge in millions
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/460bda/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can randomize the names within each gender by using `row_number()`:

```
select e.*, e2.name as new_name
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by name) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e join
     (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by dbms_random.random()) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e2
     on e.gender = e2.gender and e.seqnum = e2.seqnum;
```

This does not guarantee that names are never re-used.  In fact, that is not possible given the other constraints -- a gender might have only one name.  However, this does *randomly* assign the names, so keeping the same name is quite unlikely.

If your names can be duplicated, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=23aa0882febbc838f2c48625f15ab892) is a db<>fiddle.

You can avoid mapping the name back to the same name by using a "shifting" methodology.  However, such shifting can be undone.  The solution of randomly assigning the names with a very small probability of reassignment might be better for obfuscation.

Comment: I would think that if it is known that the names are randomized for obfuscation purposes, then it really wouldn't matter if there were an occasional use of the "real" name, in spite of the OP's "requirement" for such.